# Reading width and height of PNG header

Tags: c++, image, file, file-io, png

I am experimenting with reading the width and height of a PNG file.
This is my code:

```
struct TImageSize {
    int width;
    int height;
};

bool getPngSize(const char *fileName, TImageSize &is) {
    std::ifstream file(fileName, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::in);

    if (!file.is_open() || !file) {
        file.close();
        return false;
    }

    // Skip PNG file signature
    file.seekg(9, std::ios_base::cur);

    // First chunk: IHDR image header
    // Skip Chunk Length
    file.seekg(4, std::ios_base::cur);
    // Skip Chunk Type
    file.seekg(4, std::ios_base::cur);

    __int32 width, height;

    file.read((char*)&width, 4);
    file.read((char*)&height, 4);

    std::cout << file.tellg();

    is.width = width;
    is.height = height;

    file.close();

    return true;
}
```

If I try to read for example from [this image from Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png), I'm getting these wrong values:

> 252097920 (should be 800)
>   139985408 (should be 600)

Note that the function is *not* returning false so the contents of the width and height variables must come from the file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're off by a byte:

```
// Skip PNG file signature
file.seekg(9, std::ios_base::cur);
```

The [PNG Specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html) says the header is 8 bytes long, so you want that "9" to be an "8" instead.  Positions start at 0.

Also note that the spec says that [integers are in network (big-endian) order](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-DataRep.html#DR.Integers-and-byte-order), so you may want or need to use [ntohl()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) or otherwise convert byte order if you're on a little-endian system.

It's probably worth using [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) or [stb_image](http://nothings.org/stb_image.c) or something similar rather than attempting to parse the png yourself, though -- unless you're doing this to learn.

Comment: +1 for you both, it works now! That's just for learning by doing ;)

Answer (score 4):

When you look at [Portable Network Graphics Technical details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Technical_details), it says the signature is 8 bytes not 9.

Plus, are you sure your system has the same byte order as the PNG standard? [ntohl(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) will ensure the correct byte order. [It's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) available for windows also.

Comment: Thanks! I've accepted his answer because you were 39 seconds later than him.